# How can I (if possible) customize the "edit" view of a page?

Tags: page-layout

The question says it already. I need to find a way to customize the edit view of a sharepoint page. I mean the view that you get when you're on a page and click "Edit". Are there any options to style/customize the code without affecting how the page looks if it's NOT in edit mode?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pagelayouts `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` placeholder, you can place the `PublishingWebControls:editmodepanel` control, in which you can place a reference to a CSS which will change the look of the page while in Edit mode.

Example

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server">
    <!-- Styles for edit mode only-->
    <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/edit-mode-21.css %>"
    After="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/page-layouts-21.css %>" runat="server"/>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It would also depend on what tools you have access to. If you have SharePoint Designer or if the solution was created in Visual Studio. You could also add a Content Editor Web Part to the page to add the styles you wanted. So yes, there are many ways this could be done depending on your toolset and comfort level.